# Has Donald Trump discussed any details about his presidential library?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump

Has Donald Trump dropped any hints as to where he would site his presidential library, and how he intends to monetize it?

Comment: I asked it in good faith, as somebody who is not in the USA hence does not have an axe to grind in the current political process. I note- as a statement of fact- that past presidents have typically selected a site for their library fairly early, and I note- as another statement of fact- that the current incumbent is happy to boast about the success of his enterprises even though he has separated himself from their day-to-day operation. Hence I feel that my phrasing is grounded in fact, and is intended neither to promote nor to discredit any political cause or individual.

Comment: I voted to close this question for two reasons: (1) presidents usually discuss the details about their libraries at the end of their terms and the election is still underway, (2) the assumption that Trump will monetize his library is baseless. For the record, I would not be surprised if he actually tries to profit from his library (e.g. build it on one of his properties), but we can't assume this before he makes any kind of announcement.

Comment: @default "the assumption that Trump will monetize his library is baseless" - he did repeatedly attempt to monetize the presidency, which sets a rather relevant precedent. Also, only assuming things about Trump after he announces his intent may not work for a person who was caught lying more often than any other human in history.

Comment: @CGCampbell I note your concern, but I'm afraid that I'm sufficiently old-school that I believe that the risk of a question being unpopular should not prevent it from being asked. As far as the timing is concerned... would it have been better if I had asked during the campaign, since that might potentially have uncovered that multiple locations had been promised the library with attendant jobs etc.?

Comment: A link to an explanation what this "presidential library" thing is about would be appreciated. I live outside of the U.S. in a place where one still gets plent of exposure to the peculiarities of U.S. politics by virtue of international news, I'd say, and yet I've never heard of the custom (?) that every U.S. president gets to set up a library.

Comment: @ORMapper https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_library https://www.archives.gov/presidential-libraries and also https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/jan/10/trump-presidential-library-florida-briny-breezes with the usual caveat against politically-biased reporting.

Comment: @Peter I'm not making a statement on Trump's honesty. All I'm saying is that we can't have a reasonable discussion about his presidential library before he makes an announcement. As for now, we can answer this question with something like "No, he didn't, and we have no idea", but this isn't a very useful answer.

Comment: @defaultlocale Perhaps a difference of opinion, but if the answer is "no he didn't" I prefer creating such an answer over casting a close vote.

Comment: Subject obviously to the difficulty of "proving a negative", I agree that a consensus that Trump has remained silent on this matter would be a useful answer.